# Unable to pass my Model from my Controller to my View using Jquery.Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm relatively new to web app development, javascript and MVC so please bear with me.

I want to use the Jquery.Ajax command to post my Model to my controller.

My View:

```
@model MVC_Interface_May21.Models.DataValuesViewModel

...

<form method="post" id="testForm">

<input type="submit" class="subButton" value="Add New.." />

</form>

...

<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'>

$(document).ready(function () {

$('#testForm').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        @{var val = Json.Encode(Model);}
        var check = '@Html.Raw(val)';
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Results/AddNew',
            type: 'POST',
            //data: JSON.stringify(check),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
...

</script>
```

I haven't included the code for my Model or Controller because I don't believe they are a part of the problem. Currently, my code simply posts back to the same page. As far as I can tell the ajax command is not being executed. The debugger doesn't help me in tracing the behavior, and I am assuming that the form is simply doing it's post submit and ignoring my function.

Any help is much appreciated, and I'm sorry if this has been answered in the past. I developed my code by looking at other solutions, but I can't identify what's making mine dysfunctional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read more about it MVC, im not even sure what you are trying to do serializing the Razor Model like that,  but that is what you are getting from the server, not your HTML Form with whatever the user input is.

You can use this js function to submit a form with Ajax.

```
$(function () {
    $('#myForm').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#result').html(result);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

And use the Create Form and imput helpers/

```
@Html.BeginFor
@Html.EditorFor
```

Comment: thank you for your input. I understand that the Model is provided by the server to the client. I want to update the Model's properties with the form data from the post, and I assumed that it would be best to pass the Model back to the controller to make those changes.

Comment: You do it, but by parsing your current form and receiving a model in the controller. but you have to serialize your form not the Model.

Comment: I've taken a completely different approach and managed to produce the functionality that I need. Thanks again for your help Luis, it's been a great first experience at SO as an asker